# Diferenças entre um: Ambiente de Desenvolvimento Linux e Windows

Tags: linux, windows

Gostaria de saber quais a diferenças de desenvolvimento, entre esses dois SO.

Tenho pouco conhecimento sobre Linux, somente teórico.

Hoje, pesquisando sobre a criação de um ambiente PHP, sem usar XAMPP ou algo parecido, me deparei com a grande comparação entre os SO no desenvolvimento PHP.

Me ficando a dúvida em relação a outras plataformas ou linguagens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A grande vantagem de se desenvolver em um ambiente Linux (ou OSX, já que ambos são Unix) é que você fica muito próximo do ambiente em que trabalharia em um servidor "de verdade".

O fato do Windows não ser pensado como uma plataforma de desenvolvimento faz com que a instalação de diversas ferramentas ou aplicativos seja um pouco mais tortuosa, chegando a nem valer a pena tentar. Nesse caso, vale a pena recorrer a uma máquina virtual, Vagrant ou Docker.

Por exemplo, se você precisa desenvolver com PHP + MySQL (para dar um exemplo de um *stack* típico), no Windows é necessário instalar o XAMPP, que instala todas as ferramentas necessárias, além de um aplicativo para Git, um para SSH etc. Não raramente, são necessários ajustes para que as quebras de linhas nos arquivos sejam compatíveis com quebras de linhas de arquivos criados em sistemas Unix, já que são padrões diferentes e provavelmente seu projeto pode (e vai) envolver desenvolvedores que usam Unix — dentre outros ajustes.

Já no Linux (ou OSX), em geral você já possui, no terminal, todas as ferramentas necessárias para o desenvolvimento. Se não possui, a instalação é muito fácil:

```
brew install php-70         # no OSX
sudo apt-get install php-70 # no Ubuntu Linux
```

Além disso, a navegação em arquivos pelo terminal, com o tempo, fica muito mais ágil do que por meio de uma interface gráfica, como geralmente é o caso do Windows. E o terminal também é sua forma de trabalhar em servidores — ou seja, se você trabalha com terminal em um sistema, sabe trabalhar com ele em outros.

Enfim, essas são apenas algumas razões das quais se trabalhar em sistemas baseados em Unix é preferível a ambiente Windows.

(PS: eu não trabalho com Linux, e sim com OSX, portanto algumas informações acima pertinente a sistemas Linux podem estar incorretas.)

Comment: + 1 falou tudo. Essa era a minha realidade antes de instalar o `Ubuntu 14` na minha máquina. Usar o `GIT` via interface gráfica é "uma tortura"

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Rodrigo, somente para esclarecer mais um pouco. Isso se encaixaria a desenvolvendo baseado em outras linguagens(ferramentas) open source e multi-plataforma(Python, C++, Lua e etc) . Diferente do desenvolvimento .Net(C#), que é "focada" para o windows. Pergunto isso, pois pretendo fazer um dual-boot é instalar um SO baseado em linux, e começar a aprender, ate eu migrar de vez. Como meu foco não é somente C#, e sim as outras de mais linguagens, vale a pena verificar isso. O ubunto, seria o mais indicado?